# Why does my DataGrid have a red exclamation sign

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a WPF app with a DataGrid bound to a property in my ViewModel. The first column in the DG has a Combobox. When I click on the last row to add a new record and I select a item from the combobox, a red exclaimation sign appears in the record marker at the left and I can't edit the rest of the columns in that new row.

What would cause this to happen?

Comment: It means there was a validation error of some sort. Do you have any custom validations?

Comment: No, I don't have any validations yet. How can I see what the error is?

Comment: Check to make sure that the datatype that is being loaded matches the datatype of the Cell. If you are using the [`DataGridComboBoxColumn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcomboboxcolumn.aspx), I beleive you have to return an [Enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.aspx). Try putting a breakpoint on your CurrentCellChanged Event to see what the data is.

Comment: In case anyone else finds this - here's a useful related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099039/wpf-datagrid-validation-errors-not-clearing