# WPF Datagrid Row Validation

Tags: wpf, validation, wpfdatagrid

There seems to be a bug in WPF 4.0 DataGrids.

I'm implementing `IDataErrorInfo` on my objects, and I have an `ObservableCollection` that a datagrid binds to. I have `ValidatesOnDataErrors=True` set on the columns but nothing set on the rows. I have `UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"`

The validation works perfectly on a cell by cell level. However, when you leave a cell invalid, go to any other cell and then return to the invalid cell and enter in valid data, the cell becomes valid but the row remains invalid when it should be valid.

Comment: I have the exact same problem!

Comment: "However, when you leave a cell invalid, go to any other cell and then return to the invalid cell and enter a valid data, the cell becomes valid but the row remains invalid when it should be valid." Exactly the same problem.

Comment: Tree guys, same wpf issue and none posted code yet. That would be bad title for a movie anyway. :D Has anyone of you thought to post some code or xaml?

Comment: Have you tried it with `INotifyDataErrorInfo`? As far as I know this interface is the recommended way of notifying about validation errors.

Comment: My "super" solution was to turn off row validation because it is enough to have cell validation only and there is no any ambiguous behavior.

Comment: While property change of that changed cell leads to get the HasError of IDataErrorInfo?

Comment: Can you share with us a part of your XAML please ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF DataGrid validation errors not clearing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099039/wpf-datagrid-validation-errors-not-clearing)

Answer (score 4):

In general property validation, it will be validated once the source gets updated but in the case of a `RowValidation` you need to specify the `RowValidationRule`  to perform the `RowValidation`.

```
 <DataGrid.RowValidationRules>
       <DataErrorValidationRule ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True" ValidationStep="UpdatedValue" />
 </DataGrid.RowValidationRules>
```

Now the `DataGrid` will validates for the Rows also you can provide the `RowValidationErrorTemplate` to show the Error in Custom format.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue.  The fix for me was setting `ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True"` on the validation rule, which seems to force another validation every time the control gets updated.