# Default ValidationErrorTemplate for my custom DataGridRowHeader style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, styles

I've had the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099039/wpf-datagrid-validation-errors-not-clearing) problem and solved it with a modified version of synergetic's answer. So my style looks like this:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type DataGridRowHeader}" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRowHeader}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Control SnapsToDevicePixels="true"
                          Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
                          AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}, 
                          Path=Item.HasErrors, Converter={StaticResource 
                          BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
                          Template="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
                          AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}, 
                          Path=ValidationErrorTemplate}" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

It works well, but the `DataGridRowHeader` isn't shown in the default style anymore although (as I understand it) the default style is refered via `ValidationErrorTemplate`.

Compare

[image: this] (after adding the aforementioned style) with

[image: default style] that I want to achieve.

Any idea what I need to change to get that defaul  style? I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Nobody has an idea? :(

Comment: Okay, I gave up and solved it otherwise.